# Using OpenCV with gradle in a Spring Boot microservice: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV (OpenPNP distribution) in a Spring Boot microservice. I add it with:

```
implementation group: 'org.openpnp', name: 'opencv', version: '4.3.0-1'
```

I follow the description (I think) in https://github.com/openpnp/opencv so I add this in my @Service class:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

When I run tests I am getting:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java430 in java.library.path
```

(No other info shown in the stack trace)

What am I missing? I think that OpenPNP fork of OpenCV includes the native libraries but I am not sure how I can locate them.

Comment: In your static block, the first line add "OpenCV.loadShared();".  should fix it, as this works for me with the same version of the jar.

Comment: I added `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` according to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_face_detection_in_picture.htm) Java 8 tutorial and got the same error. @P_C Your suggestion worked, I deleted the `System.loadLibrary` line and just added line of code it at the beginning.